# Writing a Method That Returns a 2D Array in Reverse Column Major Order

Tags: java

I'm trying to reverse a 2D Array that is in column Major order:

```
int[][] g ={{9, 8, 7, 6},{5, 4, 2, 1} , {3, 9, 2, 3}};

reverseColMajor(g) = {{3, 2, 9, 3} , {1, 2, 4, 5} , {6, 7, 8, 9}};
```

Since the returned 2D Array is the same length as the original array, mat, I just tried this method.

```
public static int[][] reverseColMajor(int mat[][])
{
     int output[][] = new int[mat.length][mat[0].length];

        int Row = 0;
        int Col = 0;

      for(int r = mat.length-1; r>=0; r--)
      {
          for(int c = mat[0].length-1; c>=0; c--)
          {
              output[Row][Col] = mat[r][c];
              Col++;
          }
          Row++;
      }
      return output;
 }
```

I've tried this below but it says I'm out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Your getting an out of bounds exception because `Col` is incrementing past the bounds of your array.  You have to set your `Col` back to Zero after your inner loop finishes.

```
      for(int c = mat[0].length-1; c>=0; c--)
      {
          output[Row][Col] = mat[r][c];
          Col++;
      }
      Col=0;
      Row++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Col = 0 after the nested loop:

```
public static int[][] reverseColMajor(int mat[][])
{
     int output[][] = new int[mat.length][mat[0].length];

        int Row = 0;
        int Col = 0;

      for(int r = mat.length-1; r>=0; r--)
      {
          for(int c = mat[0].length-1; c>=0; c--)
          {
              output[Row][Col] = mat[r][c];
              Col++;
          }
          Col = 0;
          Row++;
      }
      return output;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the method in two, one for reversing a 1D array, and another for reversing a 2D array using the first one, so the methods are simpler, reusable, and very similar.

```
public static int[][] reverse(int[][] in) {
    int[][] out = new int[in.length][];
    for (int i = 0, j = in.length - 1; j >= 0; i++,j--)
        out[j] = reverse(in[i]);
    return out;
}
public static int[] reverse(int[] in) {
    int[] out = new int[in.length];
    for (int i = 0, j = in.length - 1; j >= 0; i++,j--)
        out[j] = in[i];
    return out;
}
```

*Test*

```
int[][] g = {{9, 8, 7, 6}, {5, 4, 2, 1}, {3, 9, 2, 3}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(reverse(g)));
```

*Output*

```
[[3, 2, 9, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```